# Django save a change to Database

Tags: django

I'm trying to update the *is_admin* column of the model *user_profile*. I've written the following code in views.py but it's not updating in the DB.
How can I save the change (*user_object[0].is_admin = True*) to the database?

```
def post(self, request, format=None):
    users_provided = request.data.get('user_ids')
    for each_user in users_provided:
        user_object = UserProfile.objects.filter(user__is_active=True, user_id=each_user)
        if (user_object.exists()):
            user_object[0].is_admin = True
            user_object.update()
```

Comment: `user_object[0]` will fetch that record, and alter the `.is_admin` field, but then throws it away, `user_object.update()` is used to update *in bulk*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can update the item with:

```
def post(self, request, format=None):
    users_provided = request.data.get('user_ids')
    for each_user in users_provided:
        user_object = UserProfile.objects.filter(user__is_active=True, user_id=each_user)
        user_item = user_object.first()
        if user_item:
            user_item.is_admin = True
            user_item.save()
```

We can boost the efficiency significantly by writing this as:

```
def post(self, request, format=None):
    users_provided = request.data.get('user_ids')
    UserProfile.objects.filter(
        user__is_active=True,
        user_id__in=users_provided
    ).update(is_admin=True)
```

Comment: An off-topic question. I have a model _Pizza_ which has a many-to-many relationship with the _Topping_ model. Now I want to save a Pizza named "Italian" which has 2 toppings e.g. _cheese_ and _onion_. How can I achieve that?

Comment: @AmanSharma: first you create the `Pizza` object, so something similar to `pizza = Pizza.objects.create(name='Italian')`, and then you add toppings to the many-to-many relation of the `pizza` object, so `pizza.toppings.add(cheese, onion)` where `cheese` and `onion` are the `Topping` objects.

Comment: @Wilem Van Onsem Can you please help me with this question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70244089/django-unable-to-implement-simplejwt]

Answer (score 1):

Use `user_object[0].save()`:

```py
if (user_object.exists()):
    user_object[0].is_admin = True
    user_object[0].save()
```